# Mypy No overload variant of "__sub__"

Tags: python, mypy

I have this case :

```py
def get_date_plus_n(d1 :Optional[date] , n:int) -> Optional[date] :
    if d1 :
       return d1 + n
    else :
       return None

def get_date_minus_n(d1 :Optional[date] , n:int) -> Optional[date] :
    if d1 :
       return d1 - n
    else :
       return None


def total(n:int) -> Optional[date]:
    if get_date_plus_n(n) and get_date_minus_n() :
        return get_date_plus_n(n)-  get_date_minus_n(n)
    else :
        return None
```

But I'm getting this error running total():

```
error: No overload variant of "__sub__" of "date" matches argument type "None"
note: Possible overload variants:
note:     def __sub__(self, timedelta) -> date
note:     def __sub__(self, datetime) -> NoReturn
note:     def __sub__(self, date) -> timedelta
note: Right operand is of type "Optional[date]"
```

idk how to handle this error. In the function total() I verified if the result of the previous methods are valid before applying the **sub** method, just to avoid errors. But apparently, mipy does not like that.

Comment: "But I'm getting this error running total():" No, you aren't. That isn't a runtime error, that is some `mypy` error. In any case, `mypy` won't infer that `get_date_plus_n(n)` will not return `None`. For starters, you shouldn't be calling a fucntion twice like that. Use `x = get_date_plus_n(n)` and `y = get_date_minus_n(n)` then check the type again, ie. `if x is not None and y is not None:  return x - y`. Note you should **really** try to avoid returning a union type (i.e. Optional) for this very reason

Comment: You're right, the error is when I run mypy. I tried your way, assign the result from ```get_date_plus_n``` and ```get_date_plus_n``` in new variables and validate them, it works. Thanks